# How to declare event handlers in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are three buttons. When I click on any of them - I want to see the number of clicked button in `<span>`.

```
<button>1st button</button>
<button>2nd button</button>
<button>3rd button</button>

<span></span>
```

Firstly, I decided to use for-loop, but I know, that it keeps only last value.

```
for ( var i = 0; i< 3; i++ ) {
    $('button:eq(' + i + ')').click(function() {
        $('span').append(i + 'button was clicked');
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/RefT2/)

Maybe, `$.each()` function will help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answers give you alternate/better ways of doing what you are looking for, you need a [closure (anonymous self executing function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $('button:eq(' + i + ')').click(function () {
            $('span').append((i + 1) + 'button was clicked');
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RefT2/1/

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to loop, just bind the handler and use `.index()` which returns the `index` of the selected button.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('span').append($(this).index() + 'button was clicked');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RefT2/2/

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a loop for this. You can use `.index()`

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('span').append($(this).index() + 'button was clicked');
});
```

Declaring multiple event handlers is not a good idea when you can have a single one and you can handle it according to the element it is executed on. The context provides enough information for you to use. If you use a tool to validate your code, like [JSLint](http://jslint.com/), you will find out that it advises against declaring functions within a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('button').click(function(){
        $('span').append(($(this).index()+1)  + 'button was clicked'); 
    });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RefT2/3/